# Как проверить существование атрибута класса?

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы

Я пытаюсь выполнить проверку наличия атрибута `a` в классе `Test` и оставить прежнее значение атрибута, если он имеется,  или присвоить другое, если его нет в классе. К сожалению, где-то допускаю ошибку. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как поправить код?

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.a = 'a'

        if not 'self.a' in locals():
            self.a = 'b'

    def func(self):
        print(self.a)

Test().func()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С помощью встроенной функции [hasattr](https://pythonz.net/references/named/hasattr/):

```
if not hasattr(self, "a"):
    self.a = 'b'
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, ответ смогу принять только через десять минут:)